# Entity Framework 4 search on combined fields

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I search on two combined fields. The search should happen on the SQL end if possible.

So say I have a customer table with first name and last name. I would like users to be able to search on both of those columns using a single search box.

My query currently looks like this:

```
var query = DbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(search) || c.LastName.Contains(search));
```

but it should be something like

```
var query = DbContext.Customers
     .Where(c => c.FullName.Contains(search));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not possible unless you have `FullName` column also mapped. The way around this problem can be String.Concat which is allowed in Linq-to-entities:

```
var query = DbContext.Customers
                     .Where(p => String.Concat(p.FirstName, " ", p.LastName)
                                       .Contains(search));
```

Comment: I tried adding a FullName property in a partial class, then used your String.Concat version instead of just combining the strings, and I sadly still got a "The  type member FullName is not supported in linq-to-entities" any way to get this working?

Comment: @Mvision: You cannot use non mapped property in L2E.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Is there a simple way to join only non empty values to avoid unwanted extra spaces? E.g. Say you had a middle name which is optional and you didn't want two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed column in the database and map that
e.g.

```
alter table Customer add FullName AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
```

(Not pretty I know)